# Can I use an object as parameter AND destructure it in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

Both

```js
function x(o) {
  return o.a + o.b
}
```

and

```js
function x({ a, b }) {
  return a + b
}
```

are possible. What about something like this?

```js
function x(o | { a, b }) {
  console.log('Whole thing:', o)
  return a + b
}
```

Comment: Take it as an object, then destructure in the first line...

Answer (score 1):

You could move the destructuring part inside of the function.

```
function x(o) {
    const { a, b } = o;
    console.log('Whole thing:', o)
    return a + b;
}
```